# Flatten Laravel collection to list unqiue keys in a row

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5

I'm trying to flatten a collection in Laravel 5.2 to show all the unique values from a linked table in a single row. I have three tables, Users, Organisations and User_organisation which is a linking table. Users can belong to multiple Organisations.

When joining I get the following

```
"id"    "name"  "surname"   "email"             "organisation"
"2001"  "Jim"   "Tester1"   "jim@example.com"   "ABC"
"2001"  "Jim"   "Tester1"   "jim@example.com"   "XYZ"
"2001"  "Jim"   "Tester1"   "jim@example.com"   "123"
"2004"  "Bob"   "Smith"     "bob@example.com"   "ABC"
"2004"  "Bob"   "Smith"     "bob@example.com"   "MNO"
"2006"  "Tom"   "Foo"       "tom@example.com"   "MNO"
```

But I want to transform this to the following: single row for each User listing their Organisations.

```
"2001"  "Jim"   "Tester1"   "jim@example.com"   "ABC", "XYZ", "123" 
"2004"  "Bob"   "Smith"     "bob@example.com"   "ABC", "MNO"
"2006"  "Tom"   "Foo"       "tom@example.com"   "MNO"
```

It would be even nicer if the columns aligned like so:

```
"2001"  "Jim"   "Tester1"   "jim@example.com"   "ABC", "XYZ", "123",    
"2004"  "Bob"   "Smith"     "bob@example.com"   "ABC",      ,      , "MNO"
"2006"  "Tom"   "Foo"       "tom@example.com"        ,      ,      , "MNO"
```

I don't mind if this is done with SQL or in php. I'm trying to avoid using lots of loops and was hoping for an elegant solution using the collection methods.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write SQL?

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(organisation) ... GROUP BY id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` your results:

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

You also need to use [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to handle values of a column which are different:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(organisation SEPARATOR ", "), foo, bar FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

Documentation is your friend.

**EDIT**:

By the way, it's not easy to propose good solutions without seeing any portion of your code.

```
$select = [
    'col1', 'col2', etc,
    DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(organisation SEPARATOR ", ")')
];

$whatyouwant = DB::select($select)
    ->from('yourtable')
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('someColumn', 'ASC')
    // Some more logic you need
    ->get();
```

Comment: FWIW, `','` is `GROUP_CONCAT`'s default separator—so it's only worth specifying it explicitly if you need that additional space.

Comment: Added example with Laravel Query Builder

Comment: It helps to name the result: DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(organisation SEPARATOR ", ") AS organisations')